# Infinispan CacheEntryExpired listener

Tags: java, infinispan

I am trying to set a listener for CacheEntryExpired in Infinispan. I created a test listener that just logs the expiry and the key.

The documentation (https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/8.0/apidocs/org/infinispan/notifications/cachelistener/annotation/CacheEntryExpired.html) does not state so, but It appears, that this event is invoked in an unknown future, but not necessarily after it expired. Sometimes minutes after the real expiration, sometimes after an attempt to get the value that is put with the key.

Is there some way to configure cache to speed this event up? I don't necessarily need it immediatelly, but 10 minutes after, or never is not really acceptable.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum time between when an entry expires and when it is notified is controlled by the frequency of the expiration reaper thread.  The expiration reaper thread will check all entries in memory for expiration and then all entries in the store if they are expired.  This is why in the Javadoc you linked it talks about possibly getting an expiration immediately if the reaper thread finds it.

The configuration to set the reaper frequency can be configured by invoking [1].  The default value is every minute and is enabled.  Therefore by default an entry should notify of expiration within a minute or so.  I say so because it still has to iterate upon the cache first before it can find your expired entries.

It is possible for an expiration notification to occur earlier if a user attempts to access that key when it has expired.  Note that it is possible to disable the reaper and by doing so this will be the only method to get notifications of expired entries.

[1] https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/8.2/apidocs/org/infinispan/configuration/cache/ExpirationConfigurationBuilder.html#wakeUpInterval-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-